# MVC Url.Action with 2 parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the following in my controller where I am passing in 2 parameters:

```
    url = Url.Action("ViewReq ", "ProgramT ", new   System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { id = spid pgid = pid }), "http", Request.Url.Host);
```

When I view this, it shows up as:

```
    http://localhost/Masa/ProgramT/ViewReq/20036?pgid=00001
```

I like it to show up as:

http://localhost/Masa/ProgramT/ViewReq?id=20036&pgid=00001

How do I modify the UrlAction to show this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify your default route registration in `Global.asax` so that the `{id}` token is not part of your urls. Remove it or something.

Comment: @Darvin Dimitrov  - How can I modify the Url.Action in the sample I have above so that it shows it as http://localhost/Masa/ProgramT/ViewReq?id=20036&pgid=00001 as this will give me the absolute path. Thank you

Comment: @NatePet, you can't modify Url.Action. It's a method that's part of the ASP.NET MVC framework. As I said in my answer, modify your routes, as that's what the Url.Action method uses to generate those urls.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Darin is correct.

To get the URL that you desire, just keep your URL generation code the same

```
Url.Action("ViewReq ", "ProgramT ", new   System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { id = spid, pgid = pid }), "http", Request.Url.Host);
```

Then in the Global.asax file you add the following route below the default route.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
       "YourNewRoute", // Route name
       "ProgramT/ViewReq/{id}/{pgid}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "ProgramT", action = "ViewReq",  id = UrlParameter.Optional, pgid = UrlParameter.Optional  } // Parameter defaults
   );
```

You should then see the URL as (assuming that id is 20036 and pgid is 00001)

```
http://localhost/Masa/ProgramT/ViewReq/20036?pgid=00001
```